# Cómo solucionar el 500 Internal Server Error en una app mobile online (Genexus)?

Tags: genexus

tenemos una app mobile cuyo Panel principal esta parametrizado on-line (Connectivity Support = Online).

Es una app que no tiene Transacciones.

Contamos con un IIS en la nube de Azure.

En las propiedades del Generador, tanto “Web Root” como “Services URL” reemplazamos
http://localhost/OCmobile.NETFrameworkEnvironment/
por https://mobileqa.casasco.com.ar/OCmobile/

La app mobile cuenta con 2 procedures (“prcGetTipoDocumento”, “PRecPosicion”)  que al ser online están configurados como “Expose as Web Service = True” y “Rest Protocol = True”

Luego de compilar (F5), copiamos el contenido de la carpeta
C:\Models\OCmobile\CSharpModel\web
dentro del servidor en la nube donde tenemos el IIS:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OCmobile

Seguidamente, dentro del IIS creamos una nueva aplicación (“OCmobile”) dentro del sitio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al generar una APK e instalarlo en un celular con libre navegación en internet nos da error: “Error en el servidor de la aplicación (500 - )”

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para solucionar ese error en el celular, dentro del IIS para la aplicación “OCmobile” debemos dejar Application Pool igual a “DefaultAppPool” ó  al nombre del Sitio “mobileqa.casasco.com.ar” ? y hay que hacer algo mas?

PD:  econtramos este link pero no logramos solucionar el problema. Por eso les consultamos
[https://training.genexus.com/es/aprendiendo/cursos/genexus/faqs-cursos/~10673/Error-500#:~:text=Si%20al%20ejecutar%20por%20primera,y%20con%20las%20configuraciones%20indicadas](https://training.genexus.com/es/aprendiendo/cursos/genexus/faqs-cursos/%7E10673/Error-500#:%7E:text=Si%20al%20ejecutar%20por%20primera,y%20con%20las%20configuraciones%20indicadas).

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error puede significar que el módulo URL Rewrite no está instalado en el servidor o que falta realizar el registro de las extensiones SVC en el servidor con el comando:

```
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe" –i
```

Adicionalmente, tienes que revisar en el servidor que las siguientes características estén activadas en "Activar y Desactivar características de Windows":

- Windows Communications Foundations HTTP Activation
- Windows    Communications Foundations non-HTTP Activation

Y si estás usando .NET Framework 4.5 Advanced Services > WCFServices

- HTTPActivation

Puedes leer más sobre este error en el siguiente link:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?18398,URLRewrite+-+Common+issues

Como también probar si funcionan los servicios rest en tu servidor con el siguiente .xpz:
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?18365,REST+Web+Services+Installation+Troubleshooting

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Guido.
bajamos el ZXP y probamos el procedure "RESTTesterTool".   Luego

1. Borramos la carpeta C:\Models\OCmobile\CSharpModel\mobile\Android\nobre_panel_principal
luego hicimos Build/re buill All para que regenere todos los objetos y referencias nuevamente.

3. Compilamos (F5) para que genere nuevamente el APK 
   (C:\Models\OCmobile\CSharpModel\mobile\Android\LoginOC\build\outputs\apk\debug)

3. Copie la carpeta "web" de la notebook al Azure

4. Instale la APK en el celular, y abrió correctamente el panel principal!

Problema solucionado.
Muchas gracias